# MySQL - slowly query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a search post on my forum.

1) I split search string using `explode(" ", $string);`

2) I search all `tag_id` where `tag_value` contains word - `SELECT tag_id WHERE tag_value like '%{word}%';` all results are added to array `$tags_array`

3) I created `INNER JOIN`

```
foreach ($tags_array as $k => $v) {
    if (!empty($v)) {
        $short_name = "frt_".$i++;
        $inner_array[] = " INNER JOIN forum_rel_tags as ".$short_name." ON (".$short_name.".tag_id IN (".implode(", ", $v).")) ";
        $more[] = " ".$short_name.".post_id = fp.post_id ";
    }
}
```

4) and finally I have something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(fp.post_id) AS total

FROM forum_categories c

JOIN forum_thread t USE INDEX (thread_id)
  ON t.category_id     = c.category_id
 AND t.posts_limit    <= 1
 AND t.contest_limit  <= 3
 AND (t.register_limit*86400) <= 5841372

JOIN forum_auth a
  ON a.auth_id       = c.category_id
 AND a.auth_group_id = 1
 AND a.auth_type     = 1
 AND a.auth_visible  = 1

JOIN forum_posts fp
  ON fp.thread_id    = t.thread_id
 AND fp.post_deleted = 0

JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_0
  ON frt_0.post_id = fp.post_id
 AND frt_0.tag_id IN (1000 tag_id)

JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_1
  ON frt_1.post_id = fp.post_id
 AND frt_1.tag_id IN (200 tag_id)

JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_2
  ON frt_2.post_id = fp.post_id
 AND frt_2.tag_id IN (432 tag_id)

JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_3
  ON frt_3.post_id = fp.post_id
 AND frt_3.tag_id IN (50 tag_id)
```

But this query is very slow.

What can I change to make it faster?

EXPLAIN SELECT

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys                   key         key_len     ref                                 rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          t       ref     thread_id                       thread_id   4           const                               1       Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE          c       eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY     4           pionas.t.category_id                1       Using index
1   SIMPLE          a       eq_ref  auth_type                       auth_type   10          const,pionas.c.category_id,const    1       Using where
1   SIMPLE          frt_0   range   post_id,tag_id                  tag_id      4           NULL                                372226  Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE          frt_1   range   post_id,tag_id                  tag_id      4           NULL                                37787   Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE          fp      eq_ref  PRIMARY,thread_id,post_deleted  PRIMARY     4           pionas.frt_1.post_id                1       Using where
1   SIMPLE          u       eq_ref  PRIMARY                         PRIMARY     4           pionas.fp.user_id                   1       Using index
1   SIMPLE          frt_3   range   post_id,tag_id                  tag_id      4           NULL                                23608   Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE          frt_2   ref     post_id,tag_id                  post_id     4           pionas.frt_3.post_id                296144  Using where; Using index
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_auth` (
  `auth_type` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auth_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `auth_visible` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `auth_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `auth_last_post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `forum_auth`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `auth_type` (`auth_type`,`auth_id`,`auth_group_id`);

CREATE TABLE `forum_categories` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `category_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `category_order` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `category_parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_thread` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_posts` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `forum_categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`);

CREATE TABLE `forum_posts` (
  `post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_subject` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `post_message` text NOT NULL,
  `post_create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `post_last_modify` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_count_modify` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_ip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `guest_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `guest_mail` varchar(150) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `forum_posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  ADD KEY `thread_id` (`thread_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `post_deleted` (`thread_id`,`post_deleted`),
  ADD KEY `post_create_date` (`post_create_date`),
  ADD FULLTEXT KEY `post_message` (`post_message`);

CREATE TABLE `forum_rel_tags` (
  `post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `forum_rel_tags`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `post_id` (`post_id`,`tag_id`),
  ADD KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`);


CREATE TABLE `forum_tags` (
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `tag_url` varchar(150) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `forum_tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `tag_url` (`tag_url`);

CREATE TABLE `forum_thread` (
  `thread_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `thread_subject` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `thread_desc` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `thread_create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `thread_view` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `thread_reply` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `thread_ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `guest_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `guest_mail` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `guest_can_reply` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `thread_block` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `thread_sticky` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `posts_limit` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `register_limit` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `contest_limit` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `forum_thread`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`thread_id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  ADD KEY `thread_id` (`thread_id`,`category_id`,`posts_limit`,`register_limit`,`contest_limit`);
```

Second query:

```
SELECT fp.*, u.username, u.rang, u.post, u.date_register, u.avatar, u.pkt, f.city

    FROM forum_categories c

    JOIN forum_thread t USE INDEX (thread_id)
      ON t.category_id     = c.category_id
     AND t.posts_limit    <= 1
     AND t.contest_limit  <= 3
     AND (t.register_limit*86400) <= 5841372

    JOIN forum_auth a
      ON a.auth_id       = c.category_id
     AND a.auth_group_id = 1
     AND a.auth_type     = 1
     AND a.auth_visible  = 1

    JOIN forum_posts fp
      ON fp.thread_id    = t.thread_id
     AND fp.post_deleted = 0

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_0
      ON frt_0.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_0.tag_id IN (1000 tag_id)

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_1
      ON frt_1.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_1.tag_id IN (200 tag_id)

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_2
      ON frt_2.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_2.tag_id IN (432 tag_id)

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_3
      ON frt_3.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_3.tag_id IN (50 tag_id)

    LEFT JOIN users u
      ON fp.user_id=u.user_id

    LEFT JOIN users_field f
      ON u.user_id=f.user_id

    GROUP BY fp.post_id
    ORDER BY fp.post_id DESC
    LIMIT 0,30;
```

**[EDIT]**
What you think about it:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT fp.*, u.username, u.rang, u.post, u.date_register, u.avatar, u.pkt, f.city

FROM forum_categories c

JOIN forum_thread t USE INDEX (thread_id)
  ON t.category_id     = c.category_id
 AND t.posts_limit    <= 1
 AND t.contest_limit  <= 3
 AND t.register_limit <= (5841372/86400)

JOIN forum_auth a
  ON a.auth_id       = c.category_id
 AND a.auth_group_id = 1
 AND a.auth_type     = 1
 AND a.auth_visible  = 1

JOIN forum_posts fp
  ON fp.thread_id    = t.thread_id
 AND fp.post_deleted = 0

JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_0
  ON frt_0.post_id = fp.post_id

JOIN forum_tags ft_0
  ON ft_0.tag_id = frt_0.tag_id
 AND ft_0.tag_url like '%play%'

JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_1
  ON frt_0.post_id = frt_1.post_id

JOIN forum_tags ft_1
  ON ft_1.tag_id = frt_1.tag_id
 AND ft_1.tag_url like '%how%'


JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_2
  ON frt_1.post_id = frt_2.post_id

JOIN forum_tags ft_2
  ON ft_2.tag_id = frt_2.tag_id
 AND ft_2.tag_url like '%win%'





JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_3
  ON frt_2.post_id = frt_3.post_id

JOIN forum_tags ft_3
  ON ft_3.tag_id = frt_3.tag_id
 AND ft_3.tag_url like '%to%'

LEFT JOIN users u
  ON fp.user_id=u.user_id

LEFT JOIN users_field f
  ON u.user_id=f.user_id

GROUP BY fp.post_id
ORDER BY fp.post_id DESC
```

Comment: Can't know where to start until you EXPLAIN PLAN. my guess is that you're doing a table scan. Then the inner join without an index seals the deal.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I expect to see details about how to optimize query: TABLE SCAN and INDEX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `user_id` is unique in the `users` table, the LEFT JOIN to users table is unnecessary.

There are four joins to the forum_rel_tags table; there seems to be a potential there for multiple rows to be be returned from each join; and each of those rows is going to get "matched" to the rows returned from the other joins... which is a a partial cross product i.e. the same `fp.post_id` can be "counted" multiple times.

The most likely explanation for poor performance is the absence of suitable indexes.

Some predicates e.g. `(t.register_limit*86400)<=5841372` cannot make use of an range scan operation on an index... the expression on `t.register_limit*86400` has to be evaluated for *every* row (that isn't excluded by some other predicate) before the comparison to the literal can be made.  We typically prefer to reference a *bare column* in the predicate, where it's possible to do that to return an equivalent result... e.g.

```
  t.register_limit <= (584137/86400)
```

We can re-write the query, removing the unnecessary join to the users table, to something like this:

```
  SELECT COUNT(fp.post_id) AS total

    FROM forum_categories c

    JOIN forum_thread t
      ON t.category_id     = c.category_id
     AND t.posts_limit    <= 1
     AND t.contest_limit  <= 3
     AND (t.register_limit*86400) <= 5841372

    JOIN forum_auth a
      ON a.auth_id       = c.category_id
     AND a.auth_group_id = 1
     AND a.auth_type     = 1
     AND a.auth_visible  = 1

    JOIN forum_posts fp
      ON fp.thread_id    = t.thread_id
     AND fp.post_deleted = 0

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_0
      ON frt_0.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_0.tag_id IN (1000 tag_id)

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_1
      ON frt_1.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_1.tag_id IN (200 tag_id)

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_2
      ON frt_2.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_2.tag_id IN (432 tag_id)

    JOIN forum_rel_tags frt_3
      ON frt_3.post_id = fp.post_id
     AND frt_3.tag_id IN (50 tag_id)
```

This makes it much easier to decipher the query, especially in terms of figuring out what indexes are likely to be the most appropriate for this query.

```
... ON forum_thread (category_id, posts_limit, contest_limit, register_limit)

... ON forum_auth (auth_id, auth_group, auth_type, auth_visible)

... ON forum_posts (thread_id, post_deleted, post_id)

... ON forum_rel_tags (post_id, tag_id)
```

Since these are covering indexes for the query, we expect the EXPLAIN output to include "Using index" for these tables. This is just a first cut at some indexes; these may already exist, or there may be more appropriate ordering of the columns in the indexes.

But absent table definitions, including indexes and estimated cardinalities, it's not really possible to give a more definitive answer.

---

Again...

I'm very suspicious of the partial cross product between the references to `forum_rel_tags` table. I suspect that this query can return a value for "total" that is higher than is expected. This is just a suspicion, because I don't see any specification (beyond the query) as to what result is supposed to be returned.

Comment: You have got right. I edited my queries. Firstly i want to count records who meet all conditions, and next get part of them...